# What is the electric field at a distance $r$ due to an infinitely long wire carrying a constant current $I$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields

We know that an electric field in terms of potentials is given by $\overrightarrow{E}=-\overrightarrow{\nabla }\phi -\dfrac{\partial \overrightarrow{A}}{\partial t}$. But I just came across, while solving a problem, that an electric field at a distance r due to an infinitely long wire carrying a constant current I is $\overrightarrow{E}=-\dfrac{\partial \overrightarrow{A(r)}}{\partial t}$. Why is $\overrightarrow{\nabla }\phi =0$?

I am attaching the picture of the actual question that I was solving below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wire is neutral as it contains as much positive charge as negative charge. Therefore the charge density $\rho$ is zero everywhere, and hence $\phi=0$.